# Unable to properly run an js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I made 5 buttons, an array object which has countries names, and an empty paragraph.

I want the innerHTML of the paragraph to display the corresondent name based on index of a for loop I implemented, such a way that if I click the first button the paragraph display the first country in the array and so on. But I this error in console:

> Cannot read property 'country' of undefined

this is the html:

```
<p id="par"></p>
<button class="but" id="1">1</button>
<button class="but" id="2">2</button>
<button class="but" id="3">3</button>
<button class="but" id="4">4</button>
<button class="but" id="5">5</button>
```

and this is the js:

```
var bArr = $(".but")
var paises = [
  {country: "India", growth: 35},
  {country: "Indonesia",growth: 30},
  {country: "Russia",growth: 25},
  {country: "Mars",growth: 20},
  {country: "Pluton",growth: 15}    
]

for (i = 0; i< bArr.length; i++){
  $(bArr[i]).click(function(){
    $("#par").html(paises[i].country)
  })
}
```

Please, can anyone help me figure out what's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a `for` loop. Add a click event listener to all buttons and in the event handler get the `id` attribute of the clicked button and use that to select the relevant item of array.

```js
var paises = [
  {country: "India", growth: 35},
  {country: "Indonesia",growth: 30},
  {country: "Russia",growth: 25},
  {country: "Mars",growth: 20},
  {country: "Pluton",growth: 15}
];
$(".but").click(function(){
  $("#par").text(paises[this.id-1].country);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="par"></p>
<button class="but" id="1">1</button>
<button class="but" id="2">2</button>
<button class="but" id="3">3</button>
<button class="but" id="4">4</button>
<button class="but" id="5">5</button>
```